# Custom Model Binder does not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have registered a custom model binder for MyList in global.asax. However the model binder does not fire for nested properties, for simple types it works fine. In the example below, it fires for Index() but not does not fire for Index2()

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyList), new MyListBinder());

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

**Code:**

```
public class MyListBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return new MyList();
    }
}

public class MyList
{
    public List<int> items { get; set; }
}

public class MyListWrapper
{
    public MyList listItems { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(MyList list)  // ModelBinder fires :-)
    {            
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index2(MyListWrapper wrapper) // ModelBinder does not fire! :-(
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Model binders are used to allow actions to accept complex object types as parameters. These complex types should be generated via POST requests, for example, by submitting a form. If you have a highly complex object that cannot be binded by the default model binder (or it wouldn't be effective), you can use custom model binders.

**To answer your question:**
if you don't add a custom model binder for the `MyListWrapper` class too, the BindModel(of the `MyListBinder)`won't be called in a GET request, this is how ASP.NET MVC works.
However, if you modify your code by adding a POST action with the `MyListWrapper` parameter, you can see that the BindModel method is called properly.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index2()  // ModelBinder doesn't fire
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index2(MyListWrapper wrapper) // ModelBinder fires
{
    return View();
}
```

And the Index2 view

```
@model fun.web.MyListWrapper

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.listItems)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

If you'd like "control" the action parameters in a GET request, you should use [action filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: in a POST request too the binder won't fire unless I add binder for MyListWrapper too right ?

Comment: I tried that, even with a binder for MyListWrapper, in both GET and POST requests the MyListWrapper binder gets fired but MyListBinder does not fires

Comment: The point is not get or post but that the binder must be registrated otherwise the mvc framework will nit know about it...Therevarevseveral way to do this the best way is to register your model binder JUST for a single data type your MyList...as suggested in other answers.

Comment: I know, the original answer talks about a distinction between a GET and POST request, I'm making a point that it doesn't work either way so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You defined binder for `MyList`, so it triggers only when action method input parameter is of type `MyList`.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyList), new MyListBinder());
```

If you want model binder to trigger even when your `MyList` is nested into other model, you have to do this:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(MyListBinder))] 
public class MyList
{
    public List<int> items { get; set; }
}
```

Then, model binder triggers whenever it encounters `MyList` type, even when it's nested.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, to fire the model binder for Mylist i don't need to add the attribute. Does this make the Model Binder trigger when MyList is a property of MyListWrapper?

Comment: A note for WebAPI users- decorating a nested model's class with a custom model binder attribute will unfortunately not work. I believe this has to do with how WebAPI uses formatters and deserializes the request body, while MVC does not use formatters [WebAPI differences with MVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding/).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your global:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyListWrapper), new MyListWrapperBinder());
```

And then create a MyListWrapperBinder that can handle the binding.

Comment: The question is about firing it when a custom type is a property of another type.

Comment: Bottom line is you need a ModelBinder for whatever type is being passed to your ActionMethod.

Answer (score 0):

Your model binder is matched with your MyList class, not with MyListWrapper. MyListBinder is only used with MyList class or a class which inherited from MyClass.

Comment: Please add comments under the question and not as an answer.